# Slide up modal - overlay background to kick in straight away

Tags: css

I have got a modal sliding up with key frames. I wanted the background rgba I have in the overlay to kick in straight away when the modal starts sliding up but unable to make it work. Here is my code:

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.modal{
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    animation: slidein 0.3s;
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(400px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To go from background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) to background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) you need a transition, not an animation. What does trigger the modal to slide up?

Comment: thanks, it's an OnClick function based on a state in React.

Comment: So on that click add the new `background-color` to `.overlay`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not working because you added `height:100%`and probably the parent of you `overlay` has not a fixed height set. Try this insteed:

```
 .overlay {        
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: my code is working for the slide in animation, just don't know how to do a fade in anymation from 
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) to 
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) at the same time the modal slides in.